# Optimal aspect ratio of ggplot from number of facet_grid or face_wrap()

Tags: r

I've looked for a while, but there doesn't to be a question like this. I have to produce multiple ggplots, but the number of plots generated from facet_grid() or facet_wrap() can vary. Because of this, the aspect ratio of the ggplots need to be specified for each ggplot to produce a figure with an optimal aspect ratio. Is there any method of automating this so I do not have to individually set the aspect ratio for every ggplot? In case it is important, I'm using save_plot() to export the ggplot as tiff files.

Comment: Without an applicable example (sample data, actual plotting code), there's little to say. Searches (both web-wide and within SO) for `ggplot2 aspect ratio` are generally productive, perhaps with units to `ggsave` or adding `coord_fixed(ratio=...)` to a plot. Lacking that, I don't know what problem there could be with *"individually set the aspect ratio for every ggplot"*; is it a dynamic data-sensitive ratio? (My best guess: specifically control `nrow`/`ncol` and use saved dimensions to control approxiate facet aspect ratio.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what r2evans suggested in the comments. I'll leave the answer (with minor edits) here for reference.

Specifically control nrow/ncol of the facet_grid/facet_wrap and use saved dimensions to control approximate facet aspect ratio.